# Read Parallel CMOS ADC using (STM32)DCMI interface

Tags: stm32, dma

I have an external ADC with 3 outputs, 2 bit (I0,I1) and 1 clock(clk_out). I am trying to read those pins at the falling clock edge using DCMI in NUCLEO-H743ZI2 board, I wrote a code using HAL where I set the DCMI in Slave 8 bits embedded synchro modes.

```
    #include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

DCMI_HandleTypeDef hdcmi;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_dcmi;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart3_tx;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
#define BUFFLENGTH 12 //255*255*4(bytes on pixel), in future i will use crop
uint8_t buffDMA[BUFFLENGTH];
uint32_t lines = 0; //lines = 1 after DMA transfer
uint32_t vsync = 0; //vsync = 1  after DMA transfer
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_DCMI_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_DCMI_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
   //__HAL_DCMI_ENABLE_IT(&hdcmi, DCMI_IT_FRAME);

    /* Disable unwanted HSYNC (IT_LINE)/VSYNC interrupts */
    //__HAL_DCMI_DISABLE_IT(&hdcmi, DCMI_IT_LINE | DCMI_IT_VSYNC);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
    HAL_DCMI_Start_DMA(&hdcmi, DCMI_MODE_SNAPSHOT, (uint32_t) buffDMA, (uint32_t) 4); //dma status = HALL_OK after transfer
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

The callback:

```
void HAL_DCMI_ErrorCallback(DCMI_HandleTypeDef *hdcmi){
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_14);
        }
        void HAL_DCMI_FrameEventCallback(DCMI_HandleTypeDef *hdcmi) {
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_0);
            //printf("DCMI has frame!\n\r"); //in console after transfer: "DCMI has frame!"
        }
```

Can I get some help with the code ?

Comment: do you know what DCMI stands for ? Why are you trying to read a parallel 2-bit line with it ?

Comment: You can use an ISR that triggers upon a falling/rising edge on the CLK line and read the data lines

Comment: the main reason I am using DCMI is because my ADC speed can work from 4-16MSPS and the standard ISR of NUCLEO-H743ZI is fast enough to accommodate that speed.

Comment: My adc has 4 data pin actually 2 pins for each channel Ch1 (I0,I1) and Ch2 (Q0,Q1). I was only trying to make the first channel work then I will develop the code for the second channel.

Comment: 4-16 MSPS is the sample speed, It has nothing to do with the frequency of the clock line. So what is it ? "the standard ISR of NUCLEO-H743ZI is fast enough" Do you mean "isn't fast enough" ? in that case, even if the Clk line is at 16Mhz, the MCU can run at 480 MHz which is enough to sample through an ISR.

Comment: DCMI can't work without 8 bits and without synchronisation : either hardware with Hsync and Vsync or with embedded (0x00 and 0xFF as start and stop bytes) How do you plan on doing that with only 2 data pins ? 
If you want to use a peripheral to unload your CPU, you can use SPI with only MISO and SCKL with CS active for each channel, and then cleverly combine the bytes you receive.